# jackson databind - apply modules to keys in a map

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a `Map<Duration, List<UUID>>` and a custom duration module that'll convert Duration class into a string of format `<number><time unit>` ( e.g. `Duration.ofNanos(501001001001)` to `5mins 1sec 1ms 1us 1ns`).And I am using them via a utility class defined as follows:

```java
public class JacksonUtilities {
    public static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper().configure(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        .registerModule(DurationModule.getInstance());

    private JacksonUtilities() {
    }

    public static <S> String toJsonString(S source) {
        try {
            return MAPPER.writeValueAsString(source);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
            throw new ConvertException(source, String.class, exception, false);
        }
    }

    public static <T> T fromJsonString(String jsonString, Class<T> target) {
        try {
            return MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, target);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
            throw new ConvertException(jsonString, target, exception, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `DurationModule` is the custom module that I have written. The issue I am facing while using `JacksonUtilities::toJsonString` is as follows: While using this for `Map<UUID, Duration>` the module is executed perfectly giving desired results. ( e.g. `{"2042568e-1d20-455b-a151-6315f73394dc":"5mins 1sec 1ms 1us 1ns"}` ), but while using the same function for `Map<Duration, List<UUID>>`, jackson seems to not use my module giving the following result `{"PT5M1.001001001S":["2042568e-1d20-455b-a151-6315f73394dc"]}`

I have also verified that the issue is not unique to my module as is happening with `Jdk8Module` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.16.1` as well.

how do I force jackson databind to use my custom module for map keys as well